# Selenium WebDriver_ Acessar a pagina sem abrir navegador

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Alguém sabe me informar se é possível acessar a pagina sem abrir navegador? Ou seja, fazer os testes sem abrir o browser.

Tem como? Se tem me deem uma luz.

Estou usando o navegador Firefox

Answer (score 3):

Sim. basta [instalar PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/download.html).

Então você muda o webdrive de:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

para:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

O resto do código creio que você não precisará alterar.

Comment: Perfeito, mas isso funciona em JAVA certo? e terei que usar outro navegador?

Comment: @ThiagoCosta ele é outro navegador, só que sem interface... faz tudo em background.

Comment: Complementando: dependendo da complexidade do teste, deverá ser tomado alguns cuidados com o phantonjs, ele não aceita download de arquivos como qualquer outro navegador comum e nem executa ou até mesmo reconhece o flash. Sim, são limitações bestas, mas pra testar a disponibilidade de download de um link ou verificar se tal frame que contém um elemento em flash carregou sem erros, o phantonjs não poderá fazer esse trabalho.

Comment: @ThiagoCosta funciona em Java sim.

Answer (score 1):

Tem uma maneira simples de resolver este problema…
Basta substituir a criação padrão do WebDriver

**De:**

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

**Para:**

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setHeadless(true);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Simples assim, espero ter ajudado! Até mais!